# Как использовать только целые числа в рейтинге?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ratingbar

Использую [этот](https://gjunge.github.io/rateit.js/examples/) метод для показа и редактирования рейтинга.
Вывожу рейтинг так

```html
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="rating" class="rating"/>
        <div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="5" data-rateit-ispreset="true" style="font-size:50px" data-rateit-mode="font"></div>
```

Проблема в том, что он изменяется с шагом 0.5, т.е. 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5 и т .д. до 5. а Как сделать так, чтобы шаг рейтинга был равен целому числу?

Comment: Во-первых, неплохо бы было добавить минимальный воспроизводимый пример, в вашем случае - подключить необходимый JavaScript с помощью сниппетов, чтобы отвечающим пришлось меньше копаться в документации. Во-вторых, смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует задать шаг рейтинга в JS-файле. Для этого элементу лучше всего присвоить id:

```js
$('#rating').rateit('step',1); //устанавливает шаг рейтинга равным 1
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="rating" class="rating"/>
        <div class="rateit" id="rating" data-rateit-value="5" data-rateit-ispreset="true" style="font-size:50px" data-rateit-mode="font"></div>
```